# Sound notification chrome extension, using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I was trying to make a Real time extension that plays a sound notification whenever the URL status bar shows up in chrome for work purposes.

I'm working as chat agent and whenever a chat pops up there's no sound to notifies me, It actually works but only at the start-up of any webpage, for example when I type [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) it shows the URL status bar, and it triggers the sound but after that when it shows up again for example when I click on my account, or I do any other action it doesn't make any sound, I've tried also catching an element from the webpage but still it didn't work.

Here are the scripts I have:

```
// background.js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
if (changeInfo.status === 'loading') {
// Tab is in 'loading' state, play sound notification
const audio = new Audio(chrome.runtime.getURL('sound.mp3'));
audio.play();
}
});
```

```
// contentScript.js
function checkStatusBar() {
const statusBar = document.querySelector('#status');

if (statusBar) {
const statusBarText = statusBar.innerText.toLowerCase();
if (statusBarText.includes('waiting for')) {
// Status bar shows 'waiting for', play sound notification
const audio = new Audio(chrome.runtime.getURL('sound.mp3'));
audio.play();
}
}
}

setInterval(checkStatusBar, 500); // Check every 0.5 seconds for changes
```

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "URL Status Bar Sound Notifier",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Plays a sound when the URL status bar shows 'Waiting for...'",
"permissions": ["activeTab"],
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"],
"persistent": false
},
"icons": {
"16": "icon.png",
"48": "icon.png",
"128": "icon.png"
},
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

Please I need help, It is very important for my livelihood, And thanks in advance.

I was expecting a sound notification whenever the URL status bar shows every time

Comment: The approach you've taken might not work reliably because the URL status bar is not a standard part of modern web browsers and may not be consistently available across different websites or browser versions.

Comment: But whenever a chat tab shows up the URL status bar shows up as well and it shows up like this "Waiting for (www.websitename.com)"
Is there's any other way to catch that chat tab and trigger the sound notification when it is caught?

Answer (score 0):

Update contentScript.js like this

```
// contentScript.js

// Function to send message to background script
function notifyBackgroundScript() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ chatAppeared: true });
}

// Function to check if the chat element appears
function checkChatElement() {
    const chatElement = document.querySelector('.component-navigation-item-container'); // Adjust selector according to your chat element
    if (chatElement) {
        // Chat element is found, notify background script
        notifyBackgroundScript();
        clearInterval(intervalId); // Stop checking once chat element is found
    }
}

// Check for chat element periodically
const intervalId = setInterval(checkChatElement, 1000); // Check every second
```

Modify the content script to send messages to the background script when the chat element is found.

Update background.js

```
// background.js

// Listen for messages from content scripts
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message && message.chatAppeared) {
        // Chat element appeared, trigger notifications
        chrome.notifications.create({
            type: 'basic',
            iconUrl: 'icon.png',
            title: 'Chat Notification',
            message: 'Chat is available!'
        });

        // Open a new tab with a specific URL
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'https://example.com/chat' });

        // Show a browser action pop-up
        chrome.browserAction.setPopup({ popup: 'popup.html' });
    }
});
```

Modify the background script to listen for messages from content scripts and trigger different types of notifications when the chat element is detected.

Update manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chat Notification",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Notifies when chat is available",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "notifications",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon.png",
        "48": "icon.png",
        "128": "icon.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["contentScript.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

include the necessary permissions and configurations for the combined notification methods.

Comment: Unfortunately, It didn't work out and it didn't make any sound even at the start up like it used to do I got an error saying : Cannot access a chrome:// URL
Context
_generated_background_page.html                 console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
also: Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.
Context
_generated_background_page.html
console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);

Comment: Grant necessary permissions in the manifest.json file then modify the content script to extract the URL status bar text directly from the webpage.

Comment: I'm sorry Ermi, I'm still a novice developer, Could you please guide me through? I'll update my manifest.json, There's anything else I need to do?

Comment: Make sure you have a sound file named sound.mp3 in the root directory of your extension. Adjust the file name if it's different.

Comment: The querySelector in The code, make sure you have it in your HTML

Comment: I've updated my manifest.json and still sadly, didn't work, Got an error saying:           Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'includes')                                     "if (statusBarText.includes('Waiting for')) {"  Highlighted

Comment: Do not worry, I'm sure about the mp3 file because whenever I replace the new background file with the old one, it just works fine but only at the start up of the webpage, also the querySelector i have the same as I quoted above

Comment: OK this happening, well then, that means  the executeScript method did not find the status element in the webpage. This can happen if the webpage does not have a status bar or if the status bar is not accessible through the usual means. So i updated the `checkStatusBar(tabId)` only, so just try it, then tell me

Comment: Thank you so much for trying but still didn't work, It game me an error saying:                        Cannot access a chrome:// URL                         "console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);"  HIGHLIGHTED I'm thinking of another way to trigger the sound, I got the chat element's name: component-navigation-item-container What do you think? Can we link it to the element's name, Ermi?

Comment: Sounds good, Indeed we can, by Update the background.js to listen for changes in the DOM and trigger the sound notification when the chat element appears then Using a MutationObserver to detect when the chat element is added to the DOM. Good try it!

Comment: Can you help me with that, please?
Like I said I'm still novice 

Comment: Update it for, i been trying to write it until you comment!

Comment: Sure Ermi, Take your time and thank you so much for assisting me, it means a lot to me 

Comment: Shall I leave the contentScript.js and the manifest file as they are?

Comment: Yes, you can leave the contentScript.js file as it is, or you can remove it if it's not being used for any other purpose in your extension. Since we are now detecting the chat element directly in the background script using a MutationObserver, the content script may not be necessary for this functionality.

Comment: Sadly, Still it didn't work but there are no errors this time, Here is the element line I'm trying to catch just to confirm with you: <div class="component-navigation-item-container">

Comment: I am so sorry, and the issue is that i am so overwhelmed and i needed to rewrite it with other option.

Comment: Sure take your time Ermi, Please update me if there's any news <3

Comment: I tried to simplify and make some improvements, still try it, and let me if anything goes wrong!

Comment: Unfortunately, Still it is not working :(

Comment: What do you think? Could we make an alternative notification option? such as a window that pops up or anything like that?

Comment: yes, i agree on that,   opening a popup window when the chat element appears. Shall we use chrome notification?

Comment: Can we use both chrome Pop ups, redirects and notifications, please?

Comment: Didn't work out unfortunately :(

Comment: There must be something wrong if this all don't work